# Cannot remove white and black patch on the html5 webpage in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, html

I am working on a Asp.Net MVC 4 application and due to some reasons there is a white patch visible on the top of the webpage and it is on layout page so obviously that is visible on all the pages in the application.

It looks as follows

[image]

As yo can see from the above picture, I have a container with aliceblue as its background color and I made sure that the container is distributed all over the page using following CSS

```
.container {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    *zoom: 1;
    border: none;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper" >
            <div class="float-left">

                <p class="site-title">
                    <a href="~/">
                        <img src= '@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png")' /></a>
                </p>


            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>
                    <ul  class="nav">
                        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                        {


                            @*<li><span id="currTime"></span></li>*@

                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name) + "(Admin Only)", "Index", "Admin")

                                <ul>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Internal", "Index", "Admin")
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage", "Index", "System_User")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Products", "Home")</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Logout", "User")</li>


                        }
                        else
                        {                                             
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "User")</li>

                        }
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container" style="clear:both;">

        @RenderBody()

    </div>
```

May I know where I am making a mistake?

Comment: It seems that you forgot to `clear` floating `divs`!

Comment: Please share your rendered HTML too there is some element before the container?

Comment: yeah there are few more divs like content-wrapper, float right and float-left and made their background color same as the container, I have added the html to the question please check

Comment: `content-wrapper` has the same background-color?

Comment: Yes, it does have same back ground color

Comment: It worked when I added the background for <body>